# hhvm nginx not returning value for upload_max_filesize/post_max_size

Tags: php, nginx, hhvm

I'm running hhvm (3.6) through nginx (1.6.2) via fastcgi on ubuntu (14.04).

Calling `ini_get('post_max_size')` or `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` returns an empty string within scripts returned by nginx.

However, the same simple script (test.php):

```
<?php
print_r("value: '" . ini_get('upload_max_filesize') . "'\n");
print_r("value: '" . ini_get('post_max_size') . "'\n");
```

Called by hhvm

```
hhvm -f test.php
```

Returns:

```
foo@bar:~$ hhvm -f test.php 
value: '100M'
value: '104857600'
```

Adding `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to /etc/hhvm/php.ini gives the expected values via the hhvm command line, but results in no change from hhvm within nginx, however changing other parameters in php.ini (i.e the `session.save_path`) does, so I know it's being checked.

My assumption was that `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` were getting overwritten somewhere else, but I cannot find them referenced in any other config or ini file.

Anybody have a clue they could sell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the noise, but it looks like this is a bug. https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4993